# Dots navigation with one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have one page with a dot navigation and anchors links. 
But I would like the anchors links go to the middle of the section, center verticaly in the page even with the size of the window, like this :

Large window :

[image]

Smaller window :

[image]
Moreover, how can I make the dot navigation with highlighted link ? Like this dot navigation : https://www.gumtreejobs.sg/ The dot be green when you are on the section.

**[MY JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/by7mygqj/)**

HTML :

```
<div class="nav">
        <a href="#section01">01</a>
        <a href="#section02">02</a>
        <a href="#section03">03</a>
        <a href="#section04">04</a>
</div>


<div class="content">
        <div class="section" id="section01">Section 01</div>
        <div class="section" id="section02">Section 02</div>
        <div class="section" id="section03">Section 03</div>
        <div class="section" id="section04">Section 04</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body {
  margin:0;
}


.nav {
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
}


.nav a {
  display:block;
  margin:10px;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  border-radius:100%;
  background:grey;
}

.nav a:hover {

    background: orange;
}

.nav a.active{
    background: red;
}

.section {
  height:200px;
  background:pink;
  margin:100px;

  }
```

Comment: You could inspect your sample page to see how CSS are defined

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsFiddle with what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/5oz0uzuz/1/

Sample code:

```
 $('a').click(function(){
     var $elem = $($(this).attr("href"));
   var offset = $elem.offset().top - ($(window).height() / 2) + ($elem.height() / 2);
   $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: offset
   }, 400);
   $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
   return false;
 });
```

Firstly I added the active class on the click handler and removed it from all siblings. This way you ensure that always the current item will have the class.

For the scrolling part all you needed was to add half of the height of the targeted element to the scroll.

I hope this helps

Comment: I edit my question, maybe with image it will be more understandable. Thanks

Comment: Perfect ! :D Do you know how to make the dots highlighted in red when you scroll to show the anchors position ? (without de the click, only with the scroll) Like this : https://www.gumtreejobs.sg/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5oz0uzuz/2/
This is what I tried, but I don't like when the dots highlighted : the position is not the same when you click on the anchor (center verticaly)

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside click function before animation to add active class for anchor.

```
$('.nav a').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```